# How can I display email in the browser securely with acure styling?

Tags: html, email, security, web, webclient

I'm currently working on a application which includes the functionality to display email in a web gui and now I'm wondering what's best practice for displaying email in a web browser, first I though that I should use an iframe but when looking in the source of the major web mail clients they don't seem to use iframes so that's why I'm asking here. I'm worried that styles and scripts from the mail will affect the rest of my site (also xss) but I still want the emails to be shown the way they are intended to be shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Major (web)mail clients will remove some portions of your code.
Like background-images from tables, style applied to the body tag, remove javascript, etc.
They do that to ensure it won't affect their own design and functionalities.

You have to do the same.

You would most certainly have a div where you put your cleaned email body.
How you clean the email body is up to what you agree to allow...

Comment: They normally filter any remote URLs from CSS and mail body as well as script tags to prevent CSRF- and XSS-attacks. That means "no images". However they usually leave the button to enable them after warning about possible harmful effects.

Comment: Is there any good library/class already made which handles some of this easily or should I go from scratch? And still what about style tags, if they include styles which conflict with my styles wouldn't that cause problems?

Comment: About css removal, the class definition are often removed (e.g. the <style> tag is deleted) and only the inline style stays. Your own style should thus not be altered.

Answer (score -1):

Most web clients don't accept CSS nor html nor images on emails, so that's not a problem for them. also, If you do use CSS, I think Iframe is a vaiable option.

If not, just make your css class names unique and hope for the best.